# Apps are crashing endlessly even after a factory reset, preventing me from doing anything

Tags: crashes, force-stop

Some apps are crashing endlessly, and I can't do anything because they just keep giving me the same errors.

[image: Unfortunately, Facebook has stopped.]

I've even done a wipe-out/factory reset, but the problem still persists.

This problem was first started long time ago when my battery had problem and my phone just shut down in the middle of work. When I replaced my battery and reset my phone all of my problems were solved. But recently, I mean 5-6 months after replacement, my contact and dialer app started to give me that error. I installed another dialer and contact app and I thought that if I do a reset it will fix it, and when finally I did a factory reset my setup wizard and social plugin and contact and some other apps just have this error.

My Android version is 6.0 and is stock official.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your firmware are broken, you can try to reflash the firmware, or Install a custom rom. Have also a look in xda in your phone thread maybe this problem has anyone before you.

Comment: this problem was first started long time ago when my battery had problem and my phone just shut down in the middle of work but when i replaced my battery and reset my phone all of my problems was solved but recently i mean 5-6 month after replacement my contact and dialer app start to gave me that error and i installed another dialer and cantact app and i thought that if i do a reset factory it will fix it and when finally i did a factory reset my setup wizard and social plugin and contact and some other app just have this error and i did all (FYI my android is 6 and is stock official)

Comment: Did you tried to reflash stock firmware?